# Azure Devops run bash script can't find file path

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

So I try to run a bash script in my pipeline on Azure Devops. Here is my code for it:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: '../marvel-lcg-companion/hooks/az-emulator'
```

But as you can see I received this error when I run the pipeline.

```
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/runner/work/1/marvel-lcg-companion/hooks/az-emulator'
```

So for me it is not clear how to format the file path in my YAML file. Can you guys point me in the right direction? I also tried the glob version without any success

```
**/hooks/az-emulator
```

UPDATE: my root folder is **marvel-lcg-companion**

Comment: So what is the full path to the file?

Comment: Just the one with marvel in it (that is the root folder of the git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of please ensure what you have in your working directory by adding this:

```yaml
- script: ls '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

but if `marvel-lcg-companion` is folder in root of your repo (and you use sinfle repo) you should try:

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/marvel-lcg-companion/hooks/az-emulator'
```

However if `marvel-lcg-companion` is name of your repo than rather this:

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/hooks/az-emulator'
```